# Prove that two bases for a vector space can be remade into another two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $B_{1},B_{2}$ are two bases for a vector space $V$, prove or disprove the following statement:

Given any partition $(X,Y)$ of $B_{1}$, or more specifically two subsets of $B_{1}$ such that $X\cap Y = \emptyset$ and $X\cup Y = B_{1}$,there always exists a partition $(X',Y')$ of $B_{2}$ such that $X\cup X'$ and $Y\cup Y'$ are two bases for $V$.

In fact, the finite-dimensional version of the statement has been proved to be true, but I know nothing about the infinite-dimensional version.

Comment: What do you mean by "another two bases"? If these are required to be distinct from $B_1$ and $B_2$, this is not true for the trivial vectorspace, which has only one basis.

Comment: @Fenris I took it that "partition" meant that the parts were non-empty so your counterexample would not work. But agreed, I think that it should just say at the start "$B_1, B_2$ are bases of $V$" and in the conclusion " ... are bases of $V$".

Comment: @ancientmathematician Sorry for the confusion, i just edited the question.